# EGL display not valid in Native Activity on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, egl

I have the following [Project](https://github.com/jrgleason/simpleGLESNA) I am working on. I am trying to do a simple 2D TriandleFan box.

However, when I run the project the following line fails...

```
this->display = display;
```

I can't see why it is failing can anyone else see it?

```
F/libc    ( 5178): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 5191 (gleason.gles.na)
I/ActivityManager(  278): Displayed com.gleason.gles.na/android.app.NativeActivity: +826ms
I/DEBUG   (   35): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   35): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.2.2/JB_MR1.1/576024:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   35): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   35): pid: 5178, tid: 5191, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.gleason.gles.na <<<
I/DEBUG   (   35): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     r0 00000001  r1 00000000  r2 4045e6cc  r3 404608a8
I/DEBUG   (   35):     r4 00003038  r5 00001f90  r6 2a027378  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     r8 4924ae1c  r9 00100000  sl 2a027378  fp 00000016
I/DEBUG   (   35):     ip 00000000  sp 4924adf0  lr 40427f29  pc 491468ae  cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d0  3f8000003f800000  d1  3ff000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d2  3ff0000000000000  d3  bf62cda764a98eab
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d4  4000000000000000  d5  3f40000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d6  3fe999999999999a  d7  3f8000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   35):     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   35): 
I/DEBUG   (   35): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #00  pc 000018ae  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so (Application::initWindow(android_app*)+45)
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #01  pc 00001a25  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so (Application::handleCommand(android_app*, int)+36)
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #02  pc 00001a57  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #03  pc 00001ff9  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #04  pc 00001a87  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so (Application::run()+42)
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #05  pc 00001acf  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so (android_main+54)
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #06  pc 00001b85  /data/app-lib/com.gleason.gles.na-2/libsimplena.so
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #07  pc 0000e3b8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (   35):     #08  pc 0000dab0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
```

Comment: NULL pointer dereference in Application::initWindow(), so if it's failing on that line then "this" must be NULL (and "display" the first field).  Print the value of "this" before that line to be sure.

Comment: I will confirm thanks for trying to help!